# Mozilla Thunderbird - LDAP configuration

Tags: thunderbird, ldap, address-book

I'm unable to sync an LDAP addressbook with my Mozilla Thunderbird client.......
As I found nothing really explicit about how to setup and configure an LDAP server to work with Mozilla Thunderbird, I'm putting my config here.

I read that Thunderbird uses a specific schema to store a contact informations => this schema is MozillaAbPersonAlpha which I successfully imoprted (https://serverfault.com/questions/272125/how-do-i-install-a-new-schema-for-openldap-on-debian-5-with-dynamic-config-cn-ba).

So, I created an address book:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bBwH.png]

And then an entry in it:

[image: http: //i.stack.imgur.com/o97CS.png]

But when I'm connecting to my LDAP addressbook from Thunderbird, nothing is found...

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYDj8.png]

I tried a local sync, it asked my password and then said that the replication was successful : 0 entry found.

Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 0):

Okay.. I found the solution :

- The schema "MozillaAbPersonAlpha" is unnecessary. You can create a contact just by using the schema "inetOrgPerson" only
- The configuration from my post is good, Thunderbird seems to be unable to list all the contacts... or do an offline sync (maybe I missed something in the config).
- BUT you can search for someone by typing his name in the search bar OR when you are writing an email (it will automatically send a search request to your LDAP server when you start typing the name of the person).

I mark this post as solved.